# Word for something that does the opposite of what it supposed to

Tags: synonyms

Specifically a bad outcome when a good one was meant. I'm trying to describe a cosmetic procedure meant to make you look more natural, which actually makes you look unnatural. Ideally a noun or adjective if there is one.

"He has no cosmetic embedded BLANK accessories. No inorganic betrayal of his humanity."

Comment: There could be many depending on how you want to use the word or phrase. Can you write an example sentence where they would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: *Irony* - "of or like iron" (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/irony)

Comment: @Silenus, in regards to your suggestion, may I recommend using an alternative, for example, Iron-like or Steely to avoid confusion with the humorous and dramatic notions of irony when reading the statement.

Comment: @CallumMcshane, Well, my suggestion was a (poor) attempt at irony in its humorous or dramatic sense. The irony consisted in giving a genuine suggestion of the word "irony" (to describe something that does the opposite of what it's supposed to), but with the wrong sense.

Comment: @SIlenus, Ah, apologies, I take things rather too seriously sometimes, I concede. I shall loosen up by making a funny face :P

Comment: Christ this exchange is painful. I'm sticking to the physics forums from now on.

Comment: That example makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> **Counterproductive**
>   - having the opposite of the desired effect: [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/counterproductive)
>   - thwarting the achievement of an intended goal; tending to defeat one's purpose: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/counterproductive)
>   - not helpful : making the thing you want to happen less likely to happen: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterproductive)

"He has no *counterproductive* accessories to mar his natural beauty."

"US Homeland Security Secretary Jeh Johnson Calls Proposed Muslim Ban *Counterproductive.*"

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly fitting the question, I'm feeling that '[***dud***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dud)' still may capture the sense of disappointment intended.

> NOUN

1A thing that fails to work properly or is otherwise unsatisfactory or worthless:
*'all three bombs were duds'*

Synonyms of dud in English:

> failure, flop, let-down, disappointment;

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dud